# Responsive design, display static list in a dropdown list in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I have a static list of items like this:

```
<div id="accordian">
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <p class="accordiontitle_two"><a href="/">Women Clothing</a></p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/women-coats/">Coats</a></li>
                <li><a href="/women-dresses/">Dresses</a></li>
                <li><a href="/women-jackets/">Jackets</a></li>
                <li><a href="/women-jeans/">Jeans</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to display this in a dropdown list if screen width drops beneath a certain width, e.g on mobile browsers. I'm currently using the @media screen property in CSS but I'm assuming something like this needs jquery?

My question is, how would I achieve something like this?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have a button, which you hide in screen resolutions over 520px width.

```
$("button").click(function() {
      $("#accordian ul").toggle();
});
```

When you click on , it will toggle all your ul elements inside #accordian.